# Difference in compiling for ubuntu and for Mac

Tags: c++, compilation

I have written program to work like a telephone operator for TCP clients.
A TCP client connects to the server, and then gives a channel name to the server.
If another TCP client connect to the server and give the same channel name, the server connects the 2 TCP clients together, allowing them to talk to each other without interference.

When I compile this on Mac, it works fine, but when I put it on a digital ocean droplet, I get this error during compilation. I have generated the makefile using netbeans.

This is StreamSwitch.h

```
#ifndef STREAMSWITCH_H
#define STREAMSWITCH_H
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
struct Comparator{
    int length;
    uint8_t *pointer;
};
class DiscriptorNode{
public:
    int FileDiscriptor;
    uint8_t ChannelName[1000];
    bool operator == (const DiscriptorNode& s) const { return (this->FileDiscriptor) == (s.FileDiscriptor); }
    bool operator == (const Comparator& s) const { return memcmp(s.pointer,this->ChannelName,s.length)==0; }
    bool operator != (const DiscriptorNode& s) const { return !operator==(s); }

};

class StreamConnection{
public:
    int FileDiscriptors[2];
    bool operator == (const StreamConnection& s) const { return this->FileDiscriptors == s.FileDiscriptors; }
    bool operator != (const StreamConnection& s) const { return !operator==(s); }
};

class StreamSwitch{
    list <DiscriptorNode> Unconnected;
    list <StreamConnection> Connected;
    int ServerFileDiscriptor;
    int PortNumber;
    string ErrorMessage;
public:
    StreamSwitch(int portNumber);
    void HandleCommunication();
    bool Begin();
    string GetError();
};


#endif /* STREAMSWITCH_H */
```

This is StreamSwitch.cpp

```
#include "StreamSwitch.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void remove(list<DiscriptorNode> List, list<DiscriptorNode>:: iterator &Iterator){
    list<DiscriptorNode> ::iterator temp=Iterator;
    Iterator++;
    List.erase(temp);
}
void remove(list<StreamConnection> List, list<StreamConnection>:: iterator &Iterator){
    list<StreamConnection> ::iterator temp=Iterator;
    Iterator++;
    List.erase(temp);
}

StreamSwitch::StreamSwitch(int portNumber) {
    this->PortNumber=portNumber;
}

bool StreamSwitch::Begin(){
    int ReUseSocket=1;
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;
    this->ServerFileDiscriptor=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero((char *) &ServerAddress, sizeof (ServerAddress));
    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(PortNumber);
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (setsockopt(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &ReUseSocket, sizeof (ReUseSocket)) == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (bind(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &ServerAddress, sizeof (ServerAddress)) < 0) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<"Could not bind, port "<<this->PortNumber<<" is being used";
        this->ErrorMessage=ss.str();
        return false;
    }
    listen(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, 1024);
    return true;
}
uint8_t InputDataBuffer[1000];

void StreamSwitch::HandleCommunication(){
    int maximumFd=0;
    struct timeval Timer_Variable;
    list<DiscriptorNode> ::iterator DiscIterator;
    list<StreamConnection> ::iterator ConnectionIterator;
    fd_set ReadFileDiscriptors, ExceptFileDiscriptors, WriteFileDiscriptors;
    Timer_Variable.tv_sec = 0;
    Timer_Variable.tv_usec = 100;
    FD_ZERO(&ReadFileDiscriptors);
    FD_ZERO(&WriteFileDiscriptors);
    FD_ZERO(&ExceptFileDiscriptors);
    FD_SET(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, &ReadFileDiscriptors);
    FD_SET(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, &WriteFileDiscriptors);
    FD_SET(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, &ExceptFileDiscriptors);
    if (maximumFd<this->ServerFileDiscriptor) {
        maximumFd = this->ServerFileDiscriptor;
    }
    for (DiscIterator = this->Unconnected.begin(); DiscIterator != this->Unconnected.end(); DiscIterator++) {
        FD_SET((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor, &ReadFileDiscriptors);
        FD_SET((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor, &WriteFileDiscriptors);
        FD_SET((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor, &ExceptFileDiscriptors);
        if (maximumFd < (*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor) {
            maximumFd = (*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor;
        }
    }
    for (ConnectionIterator = this->Connected.begin(); ConnectionIterator != this->Connected.end(); ConnectionIterator++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            FD_SET((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], &ReadFileDiscriptors);
            FD_SET((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], &WriteFileDiscriptors);
            FD_SET((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], &ExceptFileDiscriptors);
            if (maximumFd < (*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i]) {
                maximumFd = (*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i];
            }
        }
    }
    maximumFd++;
    select(maximumFd,&ReadFileDiscriptors,&WriteFileDiscriptors,&ExceptFileDiscriptors,&Timer_Variable);
    if(FD_ISSET(this->ServerFileDiscriptor,&ReadFileDiscriptors)){
        struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress;
        DiscriptorNode node;
        socklen_t clientLength=sizeof(ClientAddress);
        node.FileDiscriptor=accept(this->ServerFileDiscriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &ClientAddress, &clientLength);
        cout<<"Got a new connection"<<endl;
        bzero(node.ChannelName,sizeof(node.ChannelName));
        this->Unconnected.push_back(node);
    }
    for (DiscIterator = this->Unconnected.begin(); DiscIterator != this->Unconnected.end(); DiscIterator++) {

        if(FD_ISSET((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor,&ExceptFileDiscriptors)){
            close((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor);
            remove(this->Unconnected,DiscIterator);
            continue;
        }
        int errorsoc = 0;
        socklen_t len = sizeof (errorsoc);
        int retval = getsockopt((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor
                , SOL_SOCKET
                , SO_ERROR
                , &errorsoc
                , &len);
        if ((retval != 0) || (errorsoc != 0)) {
            close((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor);
            remove(this->Unconnected,DiscIterator);
            continue;
        }
        if(FD_ISSET((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor,&ReadFileDiscriptors)){
            int TransferCount;
            bzero(InputDataBuffer,sizeof(InputDataBuffer));
            TransferCount=read((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor, InputDataBuffer, sizeof(InputDataBuffer));
            if (TransferCount < 1) {
                close((*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor);
                remove(this->Unconnected,DiscIterator);
                continue;
            }
            Comparator s;
            cout<<"Got this data "<<InputDataBuffer<<endl;
            s.pointer=InputDataBuffer;
            s.length=TransferCount;
            list<DiscriptorNode>::iterator matching=std::find(this->Unconnected.begin(),this->Unconnected.end(),s);
            if(matching==this->Unconnected.end()){
                cout<<"Did not find matching"<<endl;
                memcpy((*DiscIterator).ChannelName,InputDataBuffer,TransferCount);
                continue;
            }
            cout<<"Matched "<<InputDataBuffer<<endl;
            StreamConnection connect;
            connect.FileDiscriptors[0]=(*matching).FileDiscriptor;
            connect.FileDiscriptors[1]=(*DiscIterator).FileDiscriptor;
            remove(this->Unconnected,matching);
            remove(this->Unconnected,DiscIterator);
            this->Connected.push_back(connect);
        }
    }
    for (ConnectionIterator = this->Connected.begin(); ConnectionIterator != this->Connected.end(); ConnectionIterator++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (FD_ISSET((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], &ExceptFileDiscriptors)) {
                close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i]);
                close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[1-i]);
                remove(this->Connected,ConnectionIterator);
                break;
            }
            int errorsoc = 0;
            socklen_t len = sizeof (errorsoc);
            int retval = getsockopt((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i]
                    , SOL_SOCKET
                    , SO_ERROR
                    , &errorsoc
                    , &len);
            if ((retval != 0) || (errorsoc != 0)) {
                close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i]);
                close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[1-i]);
                remove(this->Connected,ConnectionIterator);
                break;
            }
            if (FD_ISSET((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], &ReadFileDiscriptors)) {
                int TransferCount;
                bzero(InputDataBuffer, sizeof (InputDataBuffer));
                TransferCount = read((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i], InputDataBuffer, sizeof (InputDataBuffer));
                if (TransferCount < 1) {
                    close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[i]);
                    close((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[1 - i]);
                    remove(this->Connected,ConnectionIterator);
                    break;
                }
//                cout<<"This is the data received "<<InputDataBuffer<<endl;
                write((*ConnectionIterator).FileDiscriptors[1-i],InputDataBuffer,TransferCount);
            }
        }
    }
}


string StreamSwitch::GetError(){
    return this->ErrorMessage;
}
```

And this is my main

```
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "StreamSwitch.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    StreamSwitch switcher(1234);
    bool success=switcher.Begin();
    if(!success){
        cout<<switcher.GetError();
        return 0;
    }
    while(1){
        switcher.HandleCommunication();
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked my make file and confirmed that it runs the following commands for compilation

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o StreamSwitch.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/streamswitch build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o
```

This is the error I get on digital ocean droplet

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o StreamSwitch.cpp
In file included from StreamSwitch.cpp:7:0:
StreamSwitch.h:23:5: error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type
     uint8_t *pointer;
     ^
StreamSwitch.h:28:5: error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type
     uint8_t ChannelName[1000];
     ^
StreamSwitch.h: In member function ‘bool DiscriptorNode::operator==(const Comparator&) const’:
StreamSwitch.h:30:68: error: ‘const struct Comparator’ has no member named ‘pointer’
     bool operator == (const Comparator& s) const { return memcmp(s.pointer,this->ChannelName,s.length)==0; }
                                                                    ^
StreamSwitch.h:30:82: error: ‘const class DiscriptorNode’ has no member named ‘ChannelName’
     bool operator == (const Comparator& s) const { return memcmp(s.pointer,this->ChannelName,s.length)==0; }
                                                                                  ^
StreamSwitch.h:30:102: error: ‘memcmp’ was not declared in this scope
     bool operator == (const Comparator& s) const { return memcmp(s.pointer,this->ChannelName,s.length)==0; }
                                                                                                      ^
StreamSwitch.cpp: In member function ‘bool StreamSwitch::Begin()’:
StreamSwitch.cpp:34:58: error: ‘bzero’ was not declared in this scope
     bzero((char *) &ServerAddress, sizeof (ServerAddress));
                                                          ^
StreamSwitch.cpp: In member function ‘void StreamSwitch::HandleCommunication()’:
StreamSwitch.cpp:95:20: error: ‘class DiscriptorNode’ has no member named ‘ChannelName’
         bzero(node.ChannelName,sizeof(node.ChannelName));
                    ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:95:44: error: ‘class DiscriptorNode’ has no member named ‘ChannelName’
         bzero(node.ChannelName,sizeof(node.ChannelName));
                                            ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:95:56: error: ‘bzero’ was not declared in this scope
         bzero(node.ChannelName,sizeof(node.ChannelName));
                                                        ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:119:58: error: ‘bzero’ was not declared in this scope
             bzero(InputDataBuffer,sizeof(InputDataBuffer));
                                                          ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:128:15: error: ‘struct Comparator’ has no member named ‘pointer’
             s.pointer=InputDataBuffer;
               ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:130:114: error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::list<DiscriptorNode>::iterator, std::list<DiscriptorNode>::iterator, Comparator&)’
             list<DiscriptorNode>::iterator matching=std::find(this->Unconnected.begin(),this->Unconnected.end(),s);
                                                                                                                  ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:130:114: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/sstream:38,
                 from StreamSwitch.h:17,
                 from StreamSwitch.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:369:5: note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, const _CharT2&)
     find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:369:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
StreamSwitch.cpp:130:114: note:   ‘std::_List_iterator<DiscriptorNode>’ is not derived from ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>’
             list<DiscriptorNode>::iterator matching=std::find(this->Unconnected.begin(),this->Unconnected.end(),s);
                                                                                                                  ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:133:40: error: ‘class DiscriptorNode’ has no member named ‘ChannelName’
                 memcpy((*DiscIterator).ChannelName,InputDataBuffer,TransferCount);
                                        ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:133:81: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
                 memcpy((*DiscIterator).ChannelName,InputDataBuffer,TransferCount);
                                                                                 ^
StreamSwitch.cpp:168:64: error: ‘bzero’ was not declared in this scope
                 bzero(InputDataBuffer, sizeof (InputDataBuffer));
                                                                ^
```

Please help me figure out how to fix this for ubuntu, and I would love it if someone could explain how I can avoid this issue in the future.

## Edited:

I fixed the issue by adding the following headers in StreamSwitch.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <inttypes.h>
```

and removing the following from StreamSwitch.h

```
#include <string>
```

I still don't know what is going on, or why code compiled on Mac and not on the digital Ocean droplet, or how I can avoid this issue all-together in the future.

Comment: Have a look at [mcve]. Especially the "minimal" is something you could improve with the code shown in your question. Surely the problem can be demonstrated with a single file and just a few lines. That might get you an upvote or two, because the questions core does seem somewhat useful for others who are not too aware of changing standards.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Thank you for the suggestion. I have kind of been in a hurry, that's why I couldn't make a minimalistic example. I will remember to do that next time.

Comment: Suggestions, not necessarily related to the problem at hand : 1. headers in C++ have the .hpp extension usually, and 2. "using namespace std;" is bad practice. for reasons of namespace collision.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed width standard types appeared in C99 and C++11, see
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

They are declared/defined in "" and "".

So two steps to take to solve you problem platofrm independently is

1) `#include <stdint.h>` or `#include <stdint>`
2) make sure to compile by C99 or C++11 standards,
   which might need to use special comandline parameters,
   to be looked up in the documentation/help of your compilers

Note:
I extended an initially C answer to cover both. The C tag has been removed meanwhile. I think keeping the info on C is worth/harmless.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: I added the header file and compiled using 
g++ -std=c99   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/StreamSwitch.o StreamSwitch.cpp

This is the error I got
invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'C++'

Comment: Ah, I fell for you tag "C". Will add the link to C++.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I have used some of the things from C programming, but I am compiling for C++. I did mention it in the question, via the compiler commands.

Comment: I might have used C and C++ for years now, but I am still new when it comes to standards.

Comment: Also my mistake, thinking even a second while looking at your code I should have realised it is C++. ;-) On the other hand you were lucky or saved by Ajay, not get hit by the people who react harshly to even mentioning more than one language, especially when it comes to "C/C++". Keep that in mind for future questions. Good luck.

Comment: Adding c++11 std did not help. I am still face quite a few issues.

I figured out what has to be done to solve the problem for now, and edited the question to include that, but IDK the actual problem of why this issue occours, and how to avoid it.

Comment: I recommend to make a new question with the first of the remaining issues and try to focus the MCVE on that single, first issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172146/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-nitro).